# What's an efficient way of associating Post, Comment, User and Vote models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have three models Post, Comment and User (using *Devise*) associated as follows:

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :total_votes

  validates :title,   :presence => true,
                      :length   => { :maximum => 30 },
                      :uniqueness => true
  validates :content, :presence => true,
                      :uniqueness => true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

  validates_presence_of :username
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add a fourth model called **Vote** with the following conditions:

1. Both *posts* and *comments* can be voted (up and down) and show the total/sum.
2. Each *post* will have many votes (up and down) and show the total/sum.
3. Each *comment* will have many votes
4. The ID of the user should be stored each time he or she votes so I can restrict one vote per user and show the ID/name of the users who voted (not sure where to store it)

Now, I'm not sure if this is a good occasion to use *polymorphic associations* and/or *counter cache*.

What's an efficient way of associating these Post, Comment, User and Voting models?
(If possible, I would like to see how the migration would look like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect textbook example of where a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) would be useful.

Your `votes` table migration would look like this:

```
create_table :votes do |t|
  t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
  t.references :user
  t.integer :polarity
  t.integer :total
end
```

This would create a table with this schema:

```
id INTEGER
votable_id INTEGER
votable_type VARCHAR
user_id INTEGER
polarity INTEGER
total INTEGER
```

Here, `user_id` would be the person who cast the vote, `polarity` would be either '1' for an upvote or '-1' for a downvote (this lets you just sum the polarities to get upvotes and downvotes to cancel), `votable_type` would contain what the vote is for (`Post` or `Comment`), `votable_id` would contain the id of the thing the vote is for, and `total` would keep a running total of the vote sum (for efficiency).

Then your models would look like this:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :user

    before_create :update_total

    protected

    def update_total
        self.total ||= 0
        self.total += self.polarity
    end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes, :as => :votable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes, :as => :votable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah I need a total of all votes in each post and comment. So I just need to add `total INTEGER` to *vote.rb* model file?

Comment: Could you also please show me how the migration would look like?

Comment: @user734290, sorry, I meant to add the migration and forgot to. Updated.

Comment: Note that you have to update `total` manually ever time a vote is cast.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what do you mean by updating `total` manually? You mean updating it using `polarity` in the controller?

Comment: @user734290, see the `before_create` callback I added to the Vote model in my answer. That's how'd you keep a running sum in `total`.