# What does ||= do? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ||= mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556902/what-does-mean)

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104602/whats-an-efficient-way-of-associating-post-comment-user-and-vote-models-in-ra) previous question, I asked about an effective way of associating Post, User, Comment and Vote models. The Vote model has a *polarity* column which stores the vote up (+1) and vote down (-1) values. It also has a *total* column which stores the sum of all the votes in  posts and comments.

Someone gave me a detailed answer but I can't understand this part (specially the `self.total ||= 0` and `self.total += self.polarity` part and why `before_create`?):

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :user

    before_create :update_total

    protected

    def update_total
        self.total ||= 0
        self.total += self.polarity
    end
end
```

Can anyone explain the code above to me (I'm a Rails beginner)?

Comment: @Romain 46 Well, I was actually referring to the whole code (will special focus on `||=`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `self.total ||= 0` will set the value to 0 if `self.total` is nil or false. This would be good for the initial run when the model has just been created and no default value for `total` column was defined. You don't want to be doing `nil + 1` or a `nil - 1`
2. `self.total += self.polarity` is short form for `self.total = self.total + self. polarity`
3. Why `before_create`, because it logically makes sense to have the proper values in place before attempting to write the database.

Further reading: http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Answer (score 2):

self.total ||= 0 means if self.total is no value(nil), it will set value to 0

Hope it will help, I will try my best to help you let me think for the others.

For ||= do, I think this link will be useful for you->http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables